# could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Double'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am using mvc example to get data from a database. Here i got an error

> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The 'number'
>   property  on 'Employee' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value.
>   You must set this  property to a non-null value of type
>   'System.Double'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Please see my code here, i got above error.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    EmployeeContext empcon = new EmployeeContext();
    Employee employ = empcon.employees.Single(emp => emp.empid == id);
    return View(employ);
}
```

Routiconfig

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "emp", action = "Details", 
                        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

Comment: what else you need? your error message clearly says which property in which entity is set to what wrong type.

Comment: What is the type of that `number` property of your Employee class? What is the type of the corresponding column in the sql table?

Comment: Seems like you got a mismatch of types, a `double` is expected for the property `number` where you are using a `decimal`.

Comment: My question is Where i did mistake, i didn,t find, how to fix above eror and my db type is int and passing type also int

Comment: i am not using any decimal value, but why it's getting error i didnt understood

Comment: Why no one helping me,any thing wrong in my question? or my question was not clear?

Comment: go to definition of class `Employee` and see of what type is it's `number` property? If it is decimal then that's what the error message meant.

Comment: this is i mentioned their   [Key]public int empid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set;}
        public double number { get; set; }

Comment: in database i mentioned decimal(18,2) and here i mentioned as double correct,is it correct?public double number { get; set; }

Comment: try set property to decimal it worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

I think it might be because of null value conversion attempt to be stored in double.

Change your `double` to

```
double?
```

For explanation, please see the link below:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It may be the problem from DB ,from my experience I got this exception because I use data from store-procedure (generate object class using entity framework)

that one number field in my SP I supplying a data contract like this

```
CAST(NULL AS DECIMAL) AS UnitAmount
```

so in my code(after entity framework generate class) I got class that contain

```
Decimal UnitAmount{get;set;}
```

but when I run my code this error happen

> ...could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property
>   to a non-null value of type 'System.Decimal'.

it's because in my SP there is one case condition that I return my result like this so the data type return is mismatch.

```
-- if no data
Select ... ,
       0  as UnitAmount, 
       ....
```

If you don't cast/convert the result 
0     ->it will be seen as Int32 (0.00-> seen as Decimal ,)

Comment: in my case was: `case when <condition> then 1 else 0  end as Field`. And in model: `public bool Field {get;set;}`. I have the error `could not be set to a 'System.Int32' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Bool'.`. I have updated the view with: `case when <condition> then cast(1 as bit) else cast(0 as bit)  end as Field` and now all is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
public decimal number { get; set; }
```

or

```
public double number { get; set; }
```

[link](http://soabubblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/15/cf-convention-properties/)

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was in wrong DB column type - which was *numeric* and property was *long*. So I just needed to recreate column as *bigint*.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a problem with the view, returning a value when there is a null value.

Had something like "ISNULL(dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STDCOST, 0) AS STDCOST"

Then did not work.

Tried "ISNULL(dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STDCOST, 0.0) AS STDCOST"

Did not work too, but the following worked...

```
ISNULL(dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STDCOST, 0.00) AS STDCOST
```

All working now....

Answer (score 0):

I met the similiar questions, said " could not be set to a 'Decimal' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'." for one column. and I search the whold solution, found I do set this column as Int in solution. But in database, it was set as money, instead of int. so I changed it in database level. and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a situation where I was unable to change the type of the column in the table (big project, lots of dependencies).

I had a View feeding data into a Class definition, similar to this:

```
    SELECT Name,Phone,ID FROM People
```

Here, my ID was type int, but was being consumed as type string. To solve this, I instead constructed my View like this:

```
    SELECT Name, Phone, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), ID) AS ContactMethodTypeId FROM People
```

Just tuck that CONVERT in around the problematic type and it will return as the type specified. In my case, NVARCHAR.

Answer (score 0):

A decimal in SQL is not the same as a decimal in .Net. If you look at table of SqlDbType Enumeration you will find that SQL decimal is equivalent to double type.

From [C# References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Float->Double. A floating point number within the range of -1.79E +308 through 1.79E +308.

```
public double? number { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case changed code from float? to double? & it works.

```
 public double? number { get; set; }
```

my database table column type is float.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem "The 'Nr' property on 'Test' could not be set to a 'System.Decimal' value. You mast set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int64'' I had this problem '' and I was able to solve it using the correct type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: New answers to old, well-answered questions should contain ample explanation on how they complement the other answers.